# $I+J$ is the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm reading Dummit and Foote and it says:

> It is easy to see that the sum $I+J$ of the ideals $I$ and $J$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing both $I$ and $J$.

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151313/smallest-ideal-containing-i-j) but the link alluding to a proof is no longer valid. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial: Let $L$ be an ideal containing $I$ and $J$. Then since an ideal is additively closed, we must have $I + J \subseteq L$. Hence, $I+J$ is the smallest such ideal.

Comment: thanks! super clear